# Ansible - Check if string exists in file with regex

Tags: regex, ansible

I need to validate that the `PermitRootLogin` parameter is equal to "no", for example:

```
PermitRootLogin no
```

But sometimes between these words there is more than one space. For this reason I use a regex, but apparently I do it wrong. This is the line that seems to be bad:

```
when: check_config.stdout.find('PermitRootLogin\s+no') != -1
```

Any idea how to fix this?

```
- hosts: redhat
  tasks:

  - name: check file
    shell: cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    register: check_config

  - name: compare string 
    when: check_config.stdout.find('PermitRootLogin\s+no') != -1
    debug: msg="this server is ok"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q: ***"Validate that the `PermitRootLogin` parameter is equal to `no`."***

A: Put the below declaration into the *vars*

```yaml
match_lines: "{{ check_config.stdout_lines|
                 map('regex_search', '^\\s*PermitRootLogin\\s+no$')|
                 select }}"
```

and test the length of the list

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: this server is OK
      when: match_lines|length > 0
```

---

- Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    match_lines: "{{ check_config.stdout_lines|
                     map('regex_search', '^\\s*PermitRootLogin\\s+no$')|
                     select }}"
  tasks:
    - command: cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config
      register: check_config
    - debug:
        var: match_lines
    - debug:
        msg: This server is OK
      when: match_lines|length > 0
```

gives, for example (abridged)

```yaml
TASK [debug] *******************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  match_lines:
  - PermitRootLogin no

TASK [debug] *******************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: This server is OK
```

---

- Given the inventory below set hosts `-hosts: rehat`

```bash
shell> cat hosts
[redhat]
test_11
test_12
test_13
```

The playbook gives, for example (abridged)

```yaml
TASK [debug] *******************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  match_lines:
  - PermitRootLogin no
ok: [test_12] => 
  match_lines: []
ok: [test_13] => 
  match_lines: []

TASK [debug] *******************************************
skipping: [test_12]
ok: [test_11] => 
  msg: This server is OK
skipping: [test_13]
```

---

- You can use [lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html) to simplify the task if the play is running at the localhost only. For example, the playbook below gives the same result

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: This server is OK
      when: match_lines|length > 0
      vars:
        match_lines: "{{ lookup('file', '/etc/ssh/sshd_config').splitlines()|
                         map('regex_search', '^\\s*PermitRootLogin\\s+no$')|
                         select }}"
```

---

- If you want to put/replace the line in the config use [lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html). For example,

```yaml
    - lineinfile:
        path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
        regexp: '^PermitRootLogin(.*)$'
        line: 'PermitRootLogin no'
```

Comment: what would that debug task look like with a delegation to the remote machine? I find delegate_to examples mostly to localhost.

Comment: You're right. Delegating to a remote host doesn't make sense here. I updated the examples. Thank you.